# How to remove weird lines in my haplotype network using {pegas/ape}?

Tags: r, plot, dna-sequence, genetics, ape-phylo

Haplotype network attempt, I am currently trying to make a haplotype network. My start script looks like this:

```
###Packageslijst
#Install Biospring
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("msa")
install.packages('ape')
install.packages('ips')
install.packages('ggtree')
install.packages('tidyverse')
install.packages('haplotypes')
install.packages('pegas')
install.packages('stats')
BiocManager::install("ggtree")

library('Biostrings')
library('msa')
library('ape')
library('ips')
library('ggtree')
library('ggplot2')
library('haplotypes')
library('pegas')
library('stats')

#Commands-lijst:
###Import Fasta-file in R
#read FAST format file
DNAString<-readDNAStringSet('C:\\Users\\annet\\OneDrive - Wageningen University & Research\\Jaar 2\\Thesis\\Data\\Ruwe_Data\\CytoB_Fastafile.fas', format="fasta",nrec=-1L, skip=0L, seek.first.rec=FALSE,use.names=TRUE, with.qualities=FALSE) 
#Align samples to same length with ClustalW algoritm, stored as DNA stringset-object
DNAMSATEST<-msa(inputSeqs = DNAString, method = c("ClustalW"), cluster = "default", gapOpening = "default", gapExtension = "default", type = "default",order = c("aligned"), verbose = FALSE,help = FALSE)
#store multiple sequence alignments as DNAbinobject
DNABinTEST <- as.DNAbin(DNAMSATEST) 
#Demonstrate aligned sequences in phylogenetic tree<< TROUBLE
DNABinTEST

#Identified unique haplotype sequences by ingnoring matching nucleatides
#Calculate nr of haplotypes per population
HaploTEST<-haplotype(DNABinTEST, labels = NULL, strict = FALSE,
                     trailingGapsAsN = TRUE) 
HaploTEST
#Population frequency matrix was extracted > Seems correct

###Haplotype distance/heat map
dist.hamming(HaploTEST) #Calculate distance between haplotypes via Hammindistance method
###Heat map
IimpleR commands #symmetric distance matrix
heatmap() #Create heatmap based on a homemade haplotype sequence differences in pairs and putting in a symmetric matrix

###Haplotype network (3 different types)
#Options: individal datasets vs large populations vs haplotypical groups
#Extract haplotypes <works!
HaploTEST<-haplotype(DNABinTEST, labels = NULL, strict = FALSE,
                     trailingGapsAsN = TRUE) 
HaploNetTEST <- haploNet(HaploTEST, d = NULL, getProb = FALSE)
print(HaploNetTEST)
print.default(HaploNetTEST, digits = NULL, quote =TRUE, na.print = NULL, print.gap =  NULL, right = FALSE, max = NULL,useSource = TRUE)
plot(HaploNetTEST)
```

[image]

I thus followed the steps written in the manual of the [pegas](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pegas) package PlotHaploNet, however, my output does not look the same. My output has a haplotype network, but all lines are exceeding the network and keep going to outside the graph.

This is what my output looks like. I want the 'normal' haplotype, with the lines only inbetween the circles instead of through the whole picture. Does anyone have an idea what to change in my code?

Comment: Hi, could you include data accessible to other users in your reproducible example? We don't have access to your local data.

Comment: Sorry, if I may restate that; your problem isn't reproducible for us without access to your data. Therefore we're left to guess what data we either have on hand, or can get quickly is appropriate to recreate your problem. Including simple data that we can either access through some repository, or can just copy and paste out of your code is key for anyone who wants to try and provide an answer to your question.

Comment: My primary file is a Fasta-file, which always has the same format. The first rule starts with the species name and information about the sample. The second rule than contains the sequence (AGTC.....). My fasta-file contained 54 samples containing around 400 bp each.

Comment: Greetings! As another has noted, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: I actually found the problem. The command for making the figure is: [plot(HaplonetTest, size=attr(HaplonetTest, "freq"), scale.ratio=2, cex=0.6, labels=TRUE, pie=NULL, show.mutation=2, font=2, fast=TRUE). The value "show mutation" has to be larger then 1, the lines dissapear.